# Get an enumerable of all sub lists of an existing list

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have a `List<T>` and I want to obtain all possible sub lists, e.g.:

```
[A, B, C, D, E] => [[A], [A, B], [A, B, C], [A, B, C, D], [A, B, C, D, E]]
```

Is there an easy way to do obtain this new enumerable with LINQ to Objects?

**EDIT 1:**
Note that I only want "prefix lists", not all possible permutations (i.e., the shown example result is already complete).

**EDIT 2:**
Note that I want to maintain the order of the elements as well.

**EDIT 3:**
Is there a way to obtain the enumerables in O(n) instead of O(n²), i.e., by iterating over the source only once instead of multiple times and returning some kind of *view* on the data instead of a new list each time?

Comment: There is a nice blog about [permutations by Eric Lippert](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiS9afz1erLAhUDtRoKHS0KC7gQFgggMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fericlippert.com%2F2013%2F04%2F15%2Fproducing-permutations-part-one%2F&usg=AFQjCNELiYNC3091lbttaXec9OFgUqEAAw)

Comment: My question doesn't seem to be on permutations, e.g., I'm not interested in `[B, A]`?

Comment: @Yuval Izzchakov: please reopen my question, it is not a duplicate, thank you.

Comment: Do you need to maintain order of objects in your permutations? Because unless you do, how is `[A,B]` different than `[B,A]`?

Comment: i think OP needs the output as he showed, he do not need all possible combinations

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: yes, I need to maintain the order.

Comment: do you want to include like ``[B],[B,C],[B,C,D].....``?

Comment: I'm not sure but I guess the O(n) requirement is met by Yuval Itzchakov's answer.

Comment: @RenéVogt; indeed, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very naive extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetOrderedSubEnumerables<T>(
                                              this IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        var builder = new List<T>();
        foreach (var element in collection)
        {
            builder.Add(element);
            yield return builder;
        }
    }
}
```

Use:

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
    Console.WriteLine(list.GetOrderedSubEnumerables());
}
```

Result:

[image: Permutations]

Note this will return views of your data as you iterate the collection. But eventually, if you need to consume each permutation separately, you'll need to copy each `List<T>` over before yielding it back. In that case, this should do it:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetOrderedSubEnumerables<T>(
                                              this IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        var builder = new List<T>();
        foreach (var element in collection)
        {
            builder.Add(element);
            var local = new List<T>(builder);
            yield return local;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i like your solution :) +1

Comment: @EʜsᴀɴSᴀᴊᴊᴀᴅ Thanks :)

Comment: ``yield return`` will cause to create a new IEnumerable?

Comment: No, he's simply receiving views of the data each time as he iterates. As I added to my answer, if he wants to create a separate enumerator for each permutation, he'll have to either return a new `List<T>`, or yield return each item.

Comment: so same instances of string are being used again and again right?

Comment: Yes. Currently, as he's enumerating the same list is re-used over. If he needs this for printing purposes, this will do fine.

Comment: makes sense, Thanks for clarifying

Comment: Thank you, that looks very nice. My only concern is the naming. According to Wikipedia sub lists are not permutations of a list. So maybe `GetOrderedPermutations` is not the best name. I've opened a separate question discussing this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36331843/name-for-a-prefix-list-data-structure

Comment: @D.R You're right. It's definitely not a permutation, it's rather a function: X -> P(X). I changed the name to something more suitable.

Comment: By `P(X)` I mean the power set of `X`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right, your requirement is such a small subset of permutations that is has nothing to do with permutations anymore. So here my suggestion:

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(1, list.Count).
                Select(i => list.Take(i).ToList()).
                ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over a range of the number of items in your list and select the sublist like so:

```
var list = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};

var query =
    from i in Enumerable.Range(1, list.Count)
    select list.Take(i);
```

Keep in mind that if your data is not in a `List<T>` `Count` might be expensive. Also keep in mind that this iterates over your data more than once.