# Name for a "prefix list" data structure?

Tags: data-structures

I'm looking for a good name for my data structure, which holds all the "starts-with" sub lists of a list, e.g.:

```
Given list: [A, B, C]
My data structure: [ [A], [A, B], [A, B, C] ]
```

Note that my data structure does include only ordered combinations (e.g., not `[C, B, A]`) and does not include all combinations (e.g., not `[B, C]`). Only all the *prefixes* (in a way).

Is there a correct mathematical/programming term for this kind of data structure?

Comment: It is like substring of a String(letters separated by commas in order), don't know the exact mathematical term.

Answer (score 0):

Use **TRIE**. You can read more about this data structure on resources available on internet.

If we want both operations, look up and prefix search, `Trie` is suited. It is mostly used in Dictionary and Spell Checker. With `Trie`, we can support all operations like insert, search, delete in `O(n)` time where n is length of the word to be processed.

Another advantage of Trie is, we can print all words in alphabetical order.

Disadvantage of using Trie is it uses more memory. To work on that you can read about [Ternary Search Tree](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ternary-search-tree/)

Comment: Thanks for your idea, however, tries are tree-like data structures => I don't have a tree structure, so the name doesn't apply.

Comment: It does not depend on whether you have a linear or non linear data structure as a linear can be converted into non linear and vice versa. It actually depends on what is your requirement with the data structure. Thanks again